# Prove that a function is linear

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ be an connected open set, and let $f:U\to\mathbb R$.

Suppose that $\forall p\in U$, there exists a closed set $C$ with non-empty interior such that $p\in C$ and $f(x)=a_C\cdot x+b_C$ on $C$ ($a_C \in \mathbb R^k$ is a constant vector and $b_C$ is a constant for each $C$).

Prove that $f$ is linear over $U$ (that is, $f(x)=a\cdot x + b$).

It seems really intuitive and straight forward but I don't even know how to get started.

Comment: $U$ needs to be connected. When $U$ is open and connected consider two expressions of $f$ on the intersection of the interior of two of $C$ in the hypothesis. That is to say, assume $a_1 \cdot x + b_1 = a_2 \cdot x + b_2$ are equal on an open set. Then, their derivates are the same, but the derivative of the left hand side at any point is $h \mapsto a_1 \cdot h$ and that of the right hand side is $h \mapsto a_2 \cdot h,$ here $h$ runs through all of $\mathbf{R}^k.$ Then, $a_1 = a_2$ (for we have $a_1 \cdot h = a_2 \cdot h$ and we can consider $h = a_1 - a_2$). $b_1 = b_2$ by subtraction.

Comment: @WillM. I'm failing to see why $f$ couldn't be piecewise linear. More precisely, it's not clear that the interiors of the closed sets we get will necessarily intersect.

Comment: Because $U$ is open and connected, hence, path connected. The sketch of my first comment shows that on the intersection of two balls, say, $f$ is _uniquely expressible._ Consider two points and a path joining them, by openess (and compactness of the path, being the continuous image of $[0, 1]$) there are finitely many balls that cover it, and on each ball $f$ is uniquely expressible, so the unique expression "walks from ball to ball" starting at one point and ending at the other.

Comment: @WillM.  Thank you! Your last comment is very helpful and interesting. I wonder if there are any theorems related with your description? I think what we got here is that any path between any two points in $U$ must be uniquely expressed. Is my understanding correct after reading your comments?

Comment: Not only on the path, but on a "belt" around the path. The path connectedness of $U$ gives the unique expression throughout.

Comment: Is $p$ in the interior of $C?$

Comment: @WillM. Perhaps I should be more clear. I understood your comment, but the question doesn't give us an open ball around every point on which $f$ is linear, it gives us a closed set with nonempty interior containing every point on which $f$ is linear. And a (continuous) piecewise linear function satisfies this second property but not the first. Thus your argument fails.

Comment: @jgon correct, I read that $p$ was in the interior (I think I did this exercise long ago). But as written is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false as written. Consider
$f : \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} x & x\le 0 \\ 2x & x > 0 \end{cases}$$

Then we can cover $\Bbb{R}$ by the closed sets with nonempty interior $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, and $f$ is linear on each of these closed sets. Thus this is a counterexample to the claim.

The claim can be saved by requiring $p$ to be in the interior of your closed sets (which means you may as well just take open sets in the first place), and this can be proved by following the argument given by Will M. in the comments.